# setting up selenium Webdriver with options and capabilities

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

using selenium is easy though i need to start the driver with proper setup

so for now i just need that it will ignore zoom level

my code is :

```
public string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
public IWebDriver WebDriver;
var ieD = Path.Combine(path, "bin");

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
caps.SetCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
```

now my current code is only passing the path of the driver as parameter

```
WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieD);
```

how can i properly pass both capabilities and drivers path?

Comment: please mark or comment on the answer stated

Answer (score 9):

There is a `InternetExplorerOptions` class for IE options, [See source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/IE/InternetExplorerOptions.cs), which has a method `AddAdditionalCapability`. However, for your `ignoreZoomSetting`, the class has already provided a property called `IgnoreZoomLevel`, so you don't need to set capability.

On the other hand, `InternetExplorerDriver` has a constructor for both path of IEDriver and InternetExplorerOptions. [Source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/IE/InternetExplorerDriver.cs)

```
public InternetExplorerDriver(string internetExplorerDriverServerDirectory, InternetExplorerOptions options)
```

Here's how you use it:

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions {
    EnableNativeEvents = true, // just as an example, you don't need this
    IgnoreZoomLevel = true
};

// alternative
// var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
// options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;


// alternatively, you can add it manually, make name and value are correct
options.AddAdditionalCapability("some other capability", true);

WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieD, options);
```

Comment: I don't if it worked for him, but it did work for me, thanks!!